# Failed to compile values file android studio

Tags: java, android

i don't know how to solve and don't know why give me this error. Please help me, i'm new with android and don't have idea how to solve.thansk...this is the error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

and

> Failed to compile values file.

i also delete all of my xml and java files but give me always this error.

Comment: One possible reason is that you included different versions the same library twice.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the same problem by clicking the `Run with --scan` link in the log. This option shows which values are duplicated.
[image]

Comment: This should be the chosen as the correct answer